¿Como traducir una GUI de tkinter con Babel?
suponiendo que tengo 1as carpeta en_US y de_DE ambas con archivos message.po y message.mo y ahi estan las traducciones del label que le hace falta a mi codigo para que muestre la traducción ya que actualmente no traduce nada, he seguido los pasos de la siguiente pagina para crear los archivos:
https://phrase.com/blog/posts/i18n-advantages-babel-python/
import gettext
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Setup translations
localedir = 'locale'
translate = gettext.translation('messages', localedir=localedir, languages=['de'])
_ = translate.gettext

def change_language():
    language = language_var.get()
    translate = gettext.translation('messages', localedir=localedir, languages=[language])
    _ = translate.gettext

# Crear ventana
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("")

# Frame principal
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="20")
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.W, tk.E, tk.N, tk.S))
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# ComboBox para seleccionar idioma
language_var = tk.StringVar()
language_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=language_var, values=['en', 'de', 'el'])
language_combo.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
language_combo.current(0)

# Botón para cambiar el idioma
change_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Cambiar idioma", command=change_language)
change_button.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# Etiqueta para mostrar el mensaje traducido
label = ttk.Label(frame, text=_('This is a translatable string.'))
label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()



Ten en cuenta que al cambiar el idioma las nuevas llamadas a gettext.gettext(), gettext.ngettext(), etc retornaran la cadena traducida según el nuevo idioma, pero eso no afecta en nada a los widgets instanciados actualmente ya que estos obtuvieron el texto de las funciones de localización al ser creados.
Es decir, si tras cambiar el idioma instancias otro label o cualquier otro widget que haga uso de gettext.gettext() para obtener un texto, el widget obtendrá el texto de acuerdo al idioma recién establecido, pero los widgets ya creados no van a cambiar el texto mostrado, necesitas actualizarlos explícitamente.
En tu ejemplo, lo más simple es directamente:
LOCALE_DIR = './locale'

transl = gettext.translation('messages', LOCALE_DIR, languages=['de'])
transl.install()

def change_language():
    language = language_var.get()
    transl = gettext.translation('messages', LOCALE_DIR, languages=[language])
    transl.install()

    label.configure(text=_('This is a translatable string.'))

La idea básica es esta (actualizar o destruir-recrear los widgets actualmente instanciados), pero puedes llevarla a cabo de muchas formas según te convenga en tu app.
